# Is it possible to store more than 250 MB data in indexedDB in IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11, indexeddb, offline-caching, offline-storage

We need a mechanism to store data in the offline database, So I started using indexed db but came to the conclusion that in IE 11 it has a hard limit of 250 mb, so what should we use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for a mechanism to store Data offline. please
see below articles 
[Offline Storage for Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa)
and

[Offline Storage](https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c)